# Reading data from W800USB via ftdi_sio

Tags: usb, drivers

I'm trying to get data from a [W800USB RF receiver](http://www.wgldesigns.com/w800.html). The `ftdi_sio` driver handles the device:

```
[ 7279.231457] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[ 7279.231474] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7279.231485] usb 1-1.2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 7279.231493] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 7279.231501] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: A4007TCh
[ 7279.707642] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[ 7279.935302] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[ 7480.130761] ftdi_sio 1-1.2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 7480.130866] usb 1-1.2: Detected FT232RL
[ 7480.130872] usb 1-1.2: Number of endpoints 2
[ 7480.130877] usb 1-1.2: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[ 7480.130881] usb 1-1.2: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[ 7480.130919] usb 1-1.2: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[ 7480.131695] usb 1-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Then I do:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and start sending RF signals from a DS10A but there is no output. I tried using gtkterm and set baud rate to 4800, 8 bit, 1 stop bit. There is no data. I tried to [send 0xf029](http://www.wgldesigns.com/protocols/w800rf32_protocol.txt), there is no reply.

I installed VMware on the same computer, on Windows XP within VMware, powerhouse software can receive data from the device. And I can't see any data request messages from the serial port monitor. I spent hours on this thing but could not receive a single byte from Linux. What am I doing wrong?

Fedora (3.7.4-204.fc18.x86_64), tried on two computers with the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes in the form of:

```
sudo yum erase ModemManager
```